# Make <li> Element's Height Match its Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list (with 2 elements in it for this example), and I want the height of the list element to match the width of the element, when the screen width is larger than `480px`. Here is what I have tried:

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  width:90%;
  margin:5%;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#bdc3c7;
  margin:5%;
}


img {max-width:90%;}



@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  li {
    float:left;
    width:45%;
    height:45%;
      margin:2.5%;
  }

}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li>
      <h3>Logo </h3>
      <img src="https://s2.graphiq.com/sites/default/files/2307/media/images/t2/Deep_Sky_Blue_429606_i0.png" id="small_img">
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Description </h3>
      <p id="profile_des">This is some text and more text and then other things and i like pit what is happening im not sure what to type.</p>

    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Where the widths change with the screen but the heights dont match.

Also if the `li` element with the text could also be vertically centered that would be awesome. But my question is how can I have the height match the width? [FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L11pxq4/)

And I would like to do this with just `css` if possible.

Comment: @MLM sorry just added it

Comment: Use this example: https://jsfiddle.net/2fd9sp05/

Comment: I think, if you want set height value by percent, you must define them as relative or absolute.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after height. Also, the 45% for height is 45% of the parent's height and the 45% for width is 45% of the parent's width, so the 45%'s are not measuring 45% of the same thing (unless the parent happens to be a square).

Comment: Use this your code: https://jsfiddle.net/z15ym1pu/

Comment: @JagdishParmar okay thanks but I need the list elements to have a margin in between them like in my example I see that there is still `li {margin:5%}` but there is no space between them?

Answer (score 0):

Use `45vw` instead of `45%` for both your width and height;

`45vw` means 45% of the viewport's width;

You can tinker even more based on that if you want more customized width for your li, using css cal(): https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Edited code would be:

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  width:90%;
  margin:5%;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#bdc3c7;
  margin:5%;
}


img {max-width:90%;}



@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  li {
    float:left;
    width:45vw;
    height:45vw;
      margin:2.5%;
  }

}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li>
      <h3>Logo </h3>
      <img src="https://s2.graphiq.com/sites/default/files/2307/media/images/t2/Deep_Sky_Blue_429606_i0.png" id="small_img">
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Description </h3>
      <p id="profile_des">This is some text and more text and then other things and i like pit what is happening im not sure what to type.</p>

    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: This won't make the height match the width, unless the viewport always is complete squared witch it never is.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean? vw is always view port width. I didn't use vh at all here.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two problems with you solution.

1. The height of the li is not kicking in because you dont have any container/parent element with a height to calculate the percents of.
2. The 45% of the width and the height is never going to be the same.

If it was me I would make some small jQuery to fix it. It can be done fairly easy like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L11pxq4/5/)

It uses `$(window).load` to make sure that all content is loaded before i calculate all li items height and save the biggest one and then give the biggest to all the li elements, like this:

```
var biggestHeight = 0;
var thisHeight;

$('#gallery > li').each(function () {
  thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
  if (thisHeight > biggestHeight) {
    biggestHeight = thisHeight;
  }
});

$('#gallery > li').each(function () {
  $(this).outerHeight(biggestHeight);
});
```

**UPDATE:**
If it should work with window resizing as well, use min-height instead of height, and on the actually resize reset min-height and run the same functions again. Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L11pxq4/7/)

That uses this resize function:

```
$(window).resize(function () {

  var biggestHeight = 0;
  var thisHeight;

  $('#gallery > li').each(function() {
    $(this).css('min-height', 0);
  });

  $('#gallery > li').each(function () {
    thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    if (thisHeight > biggestHeight) {
      biggestHeight = thisHeight;
    }
  });

  $('#gallery > li').each(function () {
    $(this).css('min-height', biggestHeight);
  });
});
```

**UPDATE 2:** with a dynamic number of rows I would use another html structure, I would have one more level to my list. In that way we can go over each row (first `<li>` elements) and give the child inside the same height.

I changed you list structure to this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
     <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
     <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And changed the jQuery function to this:

```
$('#gallery > li').each(function () {
  thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
  $(this).find(' > ul > li').each(function() {
    $(this).css('min-height', thisHeight);
  });
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2L11pxq4/8/)

Comment: right, but the height does change as the window changes, that why I want it match the width, so the image does move outside of the list as it does in the example you provided

Comment: Do you expect the users to resize the window when the uses you solution? - My example calculate the height on window load not on resize.

Comment: okay great thanks, last thing what if there were two rows, and the `biggestHeight` in the second row is different than the `biggestHeight` in the first row, could it set `biggestHeight` by row?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Two rows as in four li elements or as a differing ul?

Comment: Yes four `li` elements all in the same `ul`, but there are two rows. On row 1there are 2 `li` and then two more on row 2, and the max height in row 1 is different than the max height in row 2.

Comment: Are you always going to have 4? Or is it going to be a dynamic number? So you maybe have 3 or 4 rows?

Comment: It is dynamic, so the number will of rows will change

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  width:90%;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#bdc3c7;
  margin:15px;
}


img {max-width:90%;}



@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  ul {
     display:table-row;
  }
  li {
    display:table-cell;
    width:45%;
    height:100%;
    border:15px solid white;
    padding:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }

}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li>
      <h3>Logo </h3>
      <img src="https://s2.graphiq.com/sites/default/files/2307/media/images/t2/Deep_Sky_Blue_429606_i0.png" id="small_img">
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>Description </h3>
      <p id="profile_des">This is some text and more text and then other things and i like pit what is happening im not sure what to type.</p>

    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: the list elements are not separated with a margin though?

Comment: You can add border-color:#xxxxxx; value to li matching your webpage bg, since margin will not affect table structure used in css code.. edited code above...

Comment: someone edited my question and it changed what it actually was, you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/2L11pxq4/ there seperated

Comment: okay, but the problem is if there are more than 2 elements they all just line up on that one row

Answer (score -2):

You can use vh or vw units for width and height.

Comment: can you elaborate please

Comment: vh or vw are related to viewport height and widths. when you resize the browser they will change accordingly. 1vw = (1/100)window width and same for vh.